# How to pass a command line option in Perl Dancer App executed by plackup

Tags: perl, dancer, plack

If I want to start a Perl Dancer app, I have to run the following command:

```
perl app.psgi
```

If I want to pass an option to the application and access it inside the script from @ARGV, I can do it like this:

```
perl app.psgi --option1 --option2
```

I can run this app using also "plackup", however I cannot pass the options like when I am running the script using Perl. The @ARGV parameters array is empty.

What can I do?
How can I pass command line options to the "app.psgi" script started from "plackup"?

Below is the file of how the script approximately looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl


use Dancer2;
use Data::Dumper;
use MIME::Base64 qw( encode_base64 );

use POSIX;

my $system = shift @ARGV || 'default_system';

print "SYSTEM: $system\n";

my $host = '127.0.0.1';
my $port = 5000;

set host => $host;
set port => $port;

get '/expenses' => sub {
    my %params = params;
    return to_json {status => 'OK'};
};

post '/expenses' => sub {
    my %params = params;
    return to_json {status => 'OK'};
};


dance;
```

Comment: How does you `app.psgi` script look like?

Comment: I've added an approximately looking script of the one I use.

Comment: According to [line 118](https://metacpan.org/release/Plack/source/lib/Plack/Util.pm#L118) in `Plack::Util` it seems `@ARGV` is cleared when running from `plack`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seem like [`plackup`](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/MIYAGAWA/Plack-0.9931/scripts/plackup) is running the app [in a sandbox environment](https://metacpan.org/release/Plack/source/lib/Plack/Util.pm#L111) where `@ARGV` is being erased.

You can still try use environment variables instead of arguments on the command line. For example, using `MY_SYSTEM` as an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Dancer2;
use Data::Dumper;
use MIME::Base64 qw( encode_base64 );
use POSIX;

print "SYSTEM: $ENV{MY_SYSTEM}\n";
# [...]
```

and then run the app using:

```
$ MY_SYSTEM=Foo plackup app.psgi
```